# after pip uninstall : pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:

Tags: pip, uninstallation, setup.py

with pip, I install a script in editable mode

```
pip install -e .
```

ok, and uninstall with

pip uninstall myscript

ok, but if I try use the uninstalled script, I get

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: myscript==0.0.1
```

why the script is not fully removed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e)

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue en the pip repository [pip uninstall does not properly cleanup bin scripts (for non-pip installs)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/513) .

and I solved with a change in the setup.py

```
--- a/setup.py
+++ b/setup.py
@@ -12 +12,5 @@ setup(
-    scripts=['bin/myscript'],
+    entry_points={
+        'console_scripts': [
+            'myscript=bin:main',
+        ],
+    },
```

and the name of script

```
renamed:    bin/myscript -> bin/__init__.py
```