# Error uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, github, pip, uninstallation

I have almost same problem as in [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619)

On my osx machine, I have a github branch installed (not on virtualenv). Below is the details:

```
$ pip freeze
...
-e git+git@github.com:cgl/CWA-Normalizer.git@de...02#egg=CWA-TwPipe-Naacl

$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ ll /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python
```

Trying to uninstall or upgrading did not work:

```
$ pip uninstall CWA-TwPipe-Naacl git+git@github.com:cgl/CWA-Normalizer.git@de4e8dae415b1b35d38eed14244127c8401ea902#egg=CWA-TwPipe-Naacl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 61, in run
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 213, in from_line
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache, constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 67, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2980, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2924, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2889, in scan_list
    raise RequirementParseError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
RequirementParseError: Expected version spec in git+git@github.com:cgl/CWA-Normalizer.git@de4e8dae415b1b35d38eed14244127c8401ea902#egg=CWA-TwPipe-Naacl at +git@github.com:cgl/CWA-Normalizer.git@de4e8dae415b1b35d38eed14244127c8401ea902#egg=CWA-TwPipe-Naacl
```

I checked /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth , both files don't have it listed.

How can I uninstall it? Where may it be listed?