# When would the -e, --editable option be useful with pip install?

Tags: python, pip

When would the `-e`, or `--editable` option be useful with `pip install`?

For some projects the last line in requirements.txt is `-e .`. What does it do exactly?

Comment: Related: [Python setup.py develop vs install](//stackoverflow.com/q/19048732); `pip install -e` runs `setup.py develop`.

Comment: if you are looking for an example of how to call `pip install -e` without `.` you can do for example: `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/` where `path/src` is the path to the src of the project where `setup.py` is at.

Comment: please visit this doc to understand it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/contributing/#getting-a-copy-of-django-s-development-version

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609943/what-is-the-use-case-for-pip-install-e

Comment: Still none of the duplicates explain in a proper way what `pip install -e .` or `-e .` in `requirements.txt` means. I understand `pip install -e package` installs the package in editable mode, placing a link in the venv site packages. But it is not so clear when `.` is specified instead of `package`. Where is the package installed then, where is the link placed, if at all? What is the difference between `pip install -r reqs.txt` with the reqs in the `reqs.txt` and `pip install -e .` with the reqs in the `setup.cfg`?

Comment: @WörDuSchnaffzig I posted an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77455221/6309) to try and address your questions from your comment.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

As the man page says it:

```
-e,--editable <path/url>
     Install a project in editable mode (i.e.  setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.
```

So you would use this when trying to install a package locally, most often in the case when you are developing it on your system. It will just link the package to the original location, basically meaning any changes to the original package would reflect directly in your environment.

Some nuggets around the same [here](http://pip-python3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20043907/1860929).

An example run can be:

```
pip install -e .
```

or

```
pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/
```

note the second is the full path to where the `setup.py` would be at.

Comment: It is still hard to understand. Of course I read the --help page. But it didnt help. Lets say I just cloned a repo called 'abc'. And I install requirements.txt which contains `-e .`. Will it make some package from setup.py editable in site-packages? Sorry, need an example maybe.

Comment: @Raituha Hmm I guess the documentation could be a bit more verbose on this

Comment: Can you give an example for: any changes to the original package would reflect directly in your environment

Comment: Do you mean change made to file followed by running python setup.py sdist again?

Comment: @variable: If you install your local project with `-e` option (`pip install -e mypackage`) and use it in your environment (e.g. within your other project like `from mypackage import custom_function`) then, when you make any change to your `custom_function`, you will able to use this updated version without re-installing it again (with `pip install` or `python setup.py`), which would happen in case of omitting `-e` flag.

Comment: @raitisd: When you run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it will install all required packages and then (if there is `-e .`) it should install current package in develop mode (e.g. you are in `mypackage` folder and it's equivalent of running `pip install -e .`, so any change in `mypackage` is directly reflected in your environment). No other packages are touched by this.

Comment: @raitisd: I have also feeling that the name of this flag (`editable`) might be a bit confusing. In fact all packages in `site-packages` are editable (you can go to this folder and try to make some modification and see, what will happen). It's just develop mode which creates link in your `site-packages` (like `mypackage.egg-link`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588871/7964098).

Comment: can you give a concrete example of how to call `pip -e`? e.g. do I need as an argument the path to the project where `setup.py` is or the `setup.py` itself? e.g. `pip -e path/src/setup.py` or `pip -e path/src/`?

Comment: if you are looking for an example of how to call `pip install -e` without `.` you can do for example: `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/` where `path/src` is the path to the src of the project where `setup.py` is at.

Comment: @Nerxis When I have installed a local project with the `-e` option, can I also add new functions and new files to the project and it will be recognized?

Comment: @saper0 Yes, it will. And that's exactly why is this option there (you are developing something and you want to test it somewhere). Just try it by yourself.

Comment: @Nerxis what then if we pull repository to new computer will those editable packages work? because I see in requirements.txt the -e path is absolute, not relative

Comment: @cikatomo What's the content of your `requirements.txt`? I do not understand your question, I am afraid you didn't understand the purpose of editable installation. It's mainly for local development. If you install your package with `-e` but do not push your changes to remote then pulling repositories from new computer will not contain those changes even when installed in editable mode.

Comment: @Nerxis, oh yes `pip install -e` to develop package locally, but then when we install it with just `pip install` to make it dependency, in requirements.txt it comes out as `my-package @file:///C:/folder/folder1/etc`. Means I have to edit manually absolute path if deploying on another computer

Answer (score 48):

**Concrete example of using `--editable` in development**

If you play with [this test package](https://github.com/cirosantilli/vcdvcd/tree/5dd4205c37ed0244ecaf443d8106fadb2f9cfbb8) as in:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/cirosantilli/vcdvcd
cd vcdvcd
git checkout 5dd4205c37ed0244ecaf443d8106fadb2f9cfbb8
python -m pip install --editable . --user
```

it outputs:

```plaintext
Obtaining file:///home/ciro/bak/git/vcdvcd
Installing collected packages: vcdvcd
  Attempting uninstall: vcdvcd
    Found existing installation: vcdvcd 1.0.6
    Can't uninstall 'vcdvcd'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py develop for vcdvcd
Successfully installed vcdvcd-1.0.6
```

The `Can't uninstall 'vcdvcd'` is normal: it tried to uninstall any existing `vcdvcd` to then replace them with the "symlink-like mechanism" that is produced in the following steps, but failed because there were no previous installations.

Then it generates a file:

```plaintext
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vcdvcd.egg-link
```

which contains:

```
/home/ciro/vcdvcd
.
```

and acts as a "symlink" to the Python interpreter.

So now, if I make any changes to the git source code under `/home/ciro/vcdvcd`, it reflects automatically on importers who can from any directory do:

```
python -c 'import vcdvcd'
```

Note however that at my `pip` version at least, binary files installed with `--editable`, such as the `vcdcat` script provided by that package via `scripts=` on `setup.py`, do not get symlinked, just copied to:

```plaintext
~/.local/bin/vcdcat
```

just like for regular installs, and therefore updates to the git repository won't directly affect them.

By comparison, a regular non `--editable` install from the git source:

```
python -m pip uninstall vcdvcd
python -m pip install --user .
```

produces a copy of the installed files under:

```plaintext
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vcdvcd
```

Uninstall of an editable package as done above requires a new enough pip as mentioned at: [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e)

Tested in Python 3.8, pip 20.0.2, Ubuntu 20.04.

**Recommendation: develop directly in-tree whenever possible**

The editable setup is useful when you are testing your patch to a package through another project.

If however you can fully test your change in-tree, just do that instead of generating an editable install which is more complex.

E.g., the vcdvcd package above is setup in a way that you can just `cd` into the source and do `./vcdcat` without pip installing the package itself (in general, you might need to install dependencies from `requirements.txt` though), and the `import vcdvcd` that that executable does (or possibly your own custom test) just finds the package correctly in the same directory it lives in.

Comment: 'Then it generates a file: ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vcdvcd.egg-link [...] and acts as a "symlink" to the Python interpreter.' --- This is what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: can you give a concrete example of how to call `pip -e`? e.g. do I need as an argument the path to the project where `setup.py` is or the `setup.py` itself? e.g. `pip -e path/src/setup.py` or `pip -e path/src/`?

Comment: @CharlieParker have you seen the mentioned package: https://github.com/cirosantilli/vcdvcd/tree/5dd4205c37ed0244ecaf443d8106fadb2f9cfbb8 ? If you follow the `git clone`, that is as concrete as it gets. You will have `cd`ed into the `setup.py` directory.

Comment: if you are looking for an example of how to call `pip install -e` without `.` you can do for example: `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/` where `path/src` is the path to the src of the project where `setup.py` is at.

Answer (score 13):

From [Working in "development" mode](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#working-in-development-mode):

> Although not required, it’s common to locally install your project in
>   “editable” or “develop” mode while you’re working on it. This allows
>   your project to be both installed and editable in project form.
>
> Assuming you’re in the root of your project directory, then run:
>
> `pip install -e .`
>
> Although somewhat cryptic, `-e` is short for
>   `--editable`, and `.` refers to the current working directory, so together, it means to install the current directory (i.e. your
>   project) in editable mode.

Some additional insights into the internals of setuptools and distutils from [“Development Mode”](http://%E2%80%9CDevelopment%20Mode%E2%80%9D):

> Under normal circumstances, the `distutils` assume that you are going to
>   build a distribution of your project, not use it in its “raw” or
>   “unbuilt” form. If you were to use the `distutils` that way, you would
>   have to rebuild and reinstall your project every time you made a
>   change to it during development.
>
> Another problem that sometimes comes up with the `distutils` is that you
>   may need to do development on two related projects at the same time.
>   You may need to put both projects’ packages in the same directory to
>   run them, but need to keep them separate for revision control
>   purposes. How can you do this?
>
> Setuptools allows you to deploy your projects for use in a common
>   directory or staging area, but without copying any files. Thus, you
>   can edit each project’s code in its checkout directory, and only need
>   to run build commands when you change a project’s C extensions or
>   similarly compiled files. You can even deploy a project into another
>   project’s checkout directory, if that’s your preferred way of working
>   (as opposed to using a common independent staging area or the
>   site-packages directory).
>
> To do this, use the `setup.py develop` command. It works very similarly
>   to `setup.py install`, except that it doesn’t actually install anything.
>   Instead, it creates a special `.egg-link` file in the deployment
>   directory, that links to your project’s source code. And, if your
>   deployment directory is Python’s `site-packages` directory, it will also
>   update the `easy-install.pth` file to include your project’s source
>   code, thereby making it available on `sys.path` for all programs using
>   that Python installation.

Comment: Are edit mode, editable mode, develop mode, and development mode all the same thing?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I believe so, but before giving you a false answer I would suggest you open a new question on SO. I would also be interested in the answer so feel free to post the link here as well.

Comment: can you give a concrete example of how to call `pip -e`? e.g. do I need as an argument the path to the project where `setup.py` is or the `setup.py` itself? e.g. `pip -e path/src/setup.py` or `pip -e path/src/`?

Comment: if you are looking for an example of how to call `pip install -e` without `.` you can do for example: `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/` where `path/src` is the path to the src of the project where `setup.py` is at.

Answer (score 9):

It is important to note that `pip uninstall` **can** **not** **uninstall** a module that has been installed with `pip install -e`. So if you go down this route, be prepared for things to get very messy if you ever need to uninstall. A **partial** solution is to (1) reinstall, keeping a record of files created, as in `sudo python3 -m setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`, and then (2) manually delete all the files listed, as in e.g. `sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tdc7201-0.1a2-py3.7.egg/` (for release 0.1a2 of module tdc7201). This does not 100% clean everything up however; even after you've done it, importing the (removed!) local library may succeed, and attempting to install the same version from a remote server may fail to do anything (because it thinks your (deleted!) local version is already up to date).

Comment: Interesting point, so essentially install with --editable is potentially irreversible? Does that mean we need to simply abandon the environment then?

Comment: It should be noted that this is no longer true as of recent versions of pip. See the following stack overflow answer comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e#comment103350606_17346619

Answer (score 2):

> Still none of the duplicates explain in a proper way what `pip install -e .` or `-e .` in `requirements.txt` means.
>
> I understand `pip install -e package` installs the package in editable mode, placing a link in the `venv` site packages.
> But it is not so clear when `.` is specified instead of `package`.
>
> Where is the package installed then, where is the link placed, if at all?
> What is the difference between `pip install -r reqs.txt` with the `reqs` in the `reqs.txt` and `pip install -e .` with the `reqs` in the `setup.cfg`?

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install?noredirect=1#comment136544835_35064426) by [Wör Du Schnaffzig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11328614/w%c3%b6r-du-schnaffzig) brings up the need for a clearer explanation of what happens when you use [`pip install -e .`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#editable-installs) or [specify `-e .` in a `requirements.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#structure), as opposed to specifying a package name.

---

When `pip install -e .` is executed, the `.` represents the current directory you are in. That is typically the root directory of the Python package you are developing.

What `pip` does in this case is that it installs the package in a way that links back to this directory, rather than copying the files to the [`site-packages`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#listing-packages) directory. That means that any changes you make to the source code will be reflected when you import the package in Python, without having to reinstall the package.

- `pip` locates the [`setup.py` (legacy)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/setup-py/#setup-py-legacy) or [`pyproject.toml`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/) file in the current directory (the `.`).
- Instead of copying the contents to `site-packages`, `pip` creates a file in `site-packages` that points to the current project directory (this is the "link" that is mentioned).
- The link is usually an `.egg-link` file (mentioned, for instance, in [`pypa/pip` issue 10476](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10476))which contains the path to the project directory and a simple `.` indicating that this directory is the one to be added to [`sys.path`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation).

---

When `-e .` is included in a `requirements.txt` file and `pip install -r requirements.txt` is run, it does the same thing as `pip install -e .` but as part of processing the requirements file.

---

To directly address Wör Du Schnaffzig's questions:

- When `.` is specified, the "package" is your project in the current directory. It is "installed" in such a way that Python will use the source code in the current directory instead of the code in `site-packages`.
- The link (in the form of an `.egg-link` file) is placed in the `site-packages` directory of the current Python environment (whether that is a virtual environment or the global Python environment).
- The difference between `pip install -r reqs.txt` with requirements specified inside `reqs.txt` and `pip install -e .` with requirements in `setup.cfg` is that:

  - the former (`pip install -r reqs.txt`) installs the packages listed in `reqs.txt` normally (copying them to `site-packages`),
  - while the latter (`pip install -e .`) installs the current directory as an editable package and processes dependencies as specified in `setup.cfg` or `setup.py`.

```bash
+-----------------+      +------------------+
| Current Dir (.) | ---> | pip install -e . |
+-----------------+      +------------------+
             |
             | (Editable Mode Link)
             v
+----------------------------+      +-----------------------+
| .egg-link in site-packages | ---> | Source Code Directory |
+----------------------------+      +-----------------------+
             |
             | (Immediate Reflection of Changes)
             v
+--------------------+
| Python Environment |
+--------------------+
```

In practice, using `-e .` is like telling Python, "Please always refer back to this specific directory for the code of this package, even if I'm running Python code from somewhere else."

The `site-packages` directory will contain a reference to the package's source code directory, not the package code itself. That allows you to work on your codebase and have those changes immediately available everywhere that Python environment is used without reinstallation.

See also "[setuptools / Development Mode (a.k.a. “Editable Installs”)](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html)"

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in previous answers, there is no symlinks that are getting created.
How does '-e' option work? -> It just updates the file "PYTHONDIR/site-packages/easy-install.pth" with the project path specified in the 'command pip install -e'.
So each time python search for a package it will check this directory as well => any changes to the files in this directory is instantly reflected.

Comment: I think this applies only to projects using a `setup.py`. With `pyproject.toml`  based projects, the entry to the easy-install.pth file is not added unless using the deprecated [compat mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#legacy-behavior) with pip. This has the implication that some IDE tools will not find pyproject.toml based editable installed packages without some extra help (like: adding a .pth file entry).

Answer (score 0):

The chief reason this is useful is because it frees your development from having to bother with all the repeated pip installs from local sources.

Imagine you have to fix a bug that requires an API change to three packages. You edit one of them, pip install it locally, test the other one on these new changes to the first, edit the second and likewise install it locally and go to edit the third package find that it has broke between the two edits and you need to go back and edit the first again, pip install etc etc. That’s a lot of development friction to have to bother with all these intermediate pip install steps.

What is more desirable in this type of multi package dependency package development is to instead install them all in editable mode. Then you can freely edit and make changes and test without ever needing to do the intermediate pip installs to get the packages working off your latest draft. You do the upfront editable install from source, get to hacking and testing and when everything is proven you can commit the changes to all packages and ship a parallel release for all packages.

Also another reason is it helps with code navigation in IDEs where you always want to navigate to dependency packages in a repo, especially a monorepo, where multiple packages live. You can enumerate in configurations many includes folders for the IDE to know of the many locations where a package can live or the interpreter that is selected in the IDE can have editable installs set to the clone of your repo and likewise be able to navigate to folders especially if those package folders do aliasing in their setup.py logic.