# pathlib Path resolves installed path directory of package instead of source code directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pathlib

I have packaged my project using setup.py and project folder structure looks like below.

```
  api-automation
  api
    packagename
       __init__.py
       user.py
       payloads
         a.json
         b.json    
  tests
    conftest.py
  setup.cfg
  setup.py
  README.rst
```

I have created virtual environment in below folder with name "myenv_1",
/Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/environments/
and i have installed above repo in this virtual environment.

I tried a lot on stackoverflow and internet but did not found answer.

code of user.py file

```
from pathlib import Path

current_dir = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)

def func():
    print("current_dir", current_dir)
```

code of conftest.py

```
from packagename.user import func

func()
```

If I run user.py file directly(python3 user.py), i will get the correct directory path as below,

```
current_dir /Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/repos/api-automation/api/packagename
```

But if I run conftest.py file(python3 conftest.py), I am getting installed path as below which i don't want and I want to get directory path like when i run user.py file directly,

```
current_dir
/Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/environments/myenv_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/packagename
```

Please help, how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you didn't use the correct option when bootstrapping your development environment.

Try:

- cleanup your development virtualenv or delete it and create a new one.
- `cd the/root/of/your/source/tree`
- `pip install -e .`

The important point is the `-e` option. Read the `pip` manual.

Comment: Thanks, pip install -e . fixed issue. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @BasavarajLamani , you may click the up triangle left of my answer if you found it useful. Gimme reputation points ;)

Comment: I do not have required reputation but I accepted your answer.