# Import error in python after all solutions tried

Tags: python, terminal

I am feeling defeated by Python to the point where I am not sure what else to try. I am running Python 3.9 and I just cant for the life of me get the imports to work correctly. Here is my directory structure:

```
hello-world-proj
|
|.. core
   |
   |..
       __init__.py
       hello_world_main.py
|
|.. test
   |
   |..
       __init__.py
       test_hello_world_main.py
```

**hello_world_main.py**

```
def hello_world_main():
   return "myString"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(hello_world_main()) # call hello_world_main()
```

**test_hello_world_main.py**

```
import unittest
import os
from core import hello_world_main

class HelloWorldTest(unittest.TestCase):
   self.assertEquals(hello_world_main(), "myString")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

When I run `python test_hello_world_main.py` I get hit with the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name hello_world_main`

I already did `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/hello-world-proj`

I am defeated and no idea what to do now. Why is this happening?

Comment: What does `__init__.py` file in `core` module look like?

Comment: @aminrd they are all empty files

Answer (score 0):

Solution one:

Having `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/hello-world-proj` already set, edit the `__init__.py` in the `core` like:

```py
from .hello_world_main import hello_world_main
```

Solution two:

Run your test from the same directory and edit the test file like:

```py
import unittest
import os
from core.hello_world_main import hello_world_main

class HelloWorldTest(unittest.TestCase):
   self.assertEquals(hello_world_main(), "myString")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

And run your command inside the `hello-world-proj` :

```
python test/test_hello_world_main.py
```

Comment: It is very weird.


It only doesnt work if I include it in the ```HelloWorldTest``` class. It works if I remove it it and put it outside like a regular script. Why is this happening? So it actually works if ```b.py``` is 

```from core.hello_world_main import hello_world_main
print(hello_world_main())
```

But it doesnt work if you icnlude it in the test like:

```class HelloWorldTest(unittest.TestCase):
   self.assertEquals(hello_world_main(), "myString")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that specific function from `hello_world_main.py`, your import statement should be `from core.hello_world_main import hello_world_main`, and if you want everything in the file, try `from core.hello_world_main import *`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

1. Add a **setup.py**
2. Install your package with: **pip install -e .**

To avoid fiddling with the `import` arguments I would instead create a `setup.py` (you probably have/need one anyway) in your top directory (hello-world-proj).

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="hello-world-proj", packages=find_packages())
```

In your project root you then pip install (preferable in your [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)) your project with a symbolic link to your project location with:

```
pip install -e .
```

Note that you **don't** have to do this after each time you change a file - just once. Read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667164/3635260)

After that you can use your current `from core import hello_world_main` in you test file:

```
import unittest
from core import hello_world_main

class HelloWorldTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hello_world(self):
        self.assertEqual(hello_world_main.hello_world_main(), "myString")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```