# Jupyter running different version of uninstalled library?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

So I was trying to modify an existing library and instead of doing it the smart way and using [`pip -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install) I instead just installed the libraries, then swapped the modified files for whatever changes I wanted. For example if I had:

```
Library A/ 
---doSomethingA.py 
---otherFiles.py
```

I just deleted `doSomethingA.py` and replaced it with my version of `doSomethingA.py`. Theoretically I figured, because im editing the file locally, it should still work as planned for my library with whatever extra functionality I want.

HOWEVER.... its basically going crazy. While I can see my edited changes in the file, when I run the library its obviously not running that file. I did things like:

1. commenting out the whole file (still runs somehow)
2. Actually uninstalling the library and part of another script using `doSomethingA.py` it still runs?? (i.e Something like `import libraryA` works on `JupyerHub`, but not on the `putty` terminal... ?)

I've obviously come to the conclusion that its not running the file that it says that it is (and trust me I've checked the path of the file like 10 times).

**My question is:**

- How is this possible? What are the places that python would store another copy of the file etc?

I've also deleted the `__pychache__`, but I can't think of anything else to do. Is my best option to just give up and create a new virtual environment, etc?

Comment: Did you remember to restart Python?

Comment: @user2357112 Do you just mean re-starting the python kernel? Because I have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are running on jupyter hub.

This means that your python is running remotly on the server and the framework is taking care to synch your local project (but not the installed libraries).

The python on the server is not aware of your local change.

As a temporary mitigation you can copy the installed library to you project root.

Comment: Ah so you are saying that Jupyter Hub will check and update changes from `ProjectA` everytime I make them, but if I install a `LibraryA` it will only sync once with that library once its installed? I dont understand why it would still be partially functioning after an uninstall however

Comment: This is usually what happens in remote interpreters. The site-package is large and sync is expensive. user project is usually lean.

Comment: I just moved off of JupyterHub for the time being but your answer was a lifesaver, thanks :)