# How to get JupyterHub to re-sync site-packages/libraries?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

So I recently had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701115/jupyter-running-different-version-of-uninstalled-library#58701256) question where, among other problems, a completely commented out file was still running and working on JupyerHub, but not on the terminal. I figured out this is due to the fact that I was modifying the library files locally, and JupyterHub does not always re-sync the `site-packages`/libraries.

However, is there a way to make JupyterHub do this as the user? Basically, I want the following to happen:

```
1. pip install LibraryA
2. modify file within LibraryA, doSomethingLibA.py
3. run script on JupyterHub using updated version of LibraryA
```

I have tried re-starting the kernel, but that didn't seem to solve it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try `del sys.modules[your_module.__name__]; import your_module`, but be careful as some objects can still hold a reference to objects from the old module.