# Download dependencies declared in pyproject.toml using Pip

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I have a Python project that doesn't contain `requirements.txt`.
But it has a `pyproject.toml` file.

How can I download packages (dependencies) required by this Python project and declared in `pyproject.toml` using the Pip package manager (instead of the build tool Poetry).

So instead of `pip download -r requirements.txt`, something like `pip download -r pyproject.toml`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install

Answer (score 53):

Here is an example of .toml file:

```yaml
[build-system]
requires = [
    "flit_core >=3.2,<4",
]
build-backend = "flit_core.buildapi"

[project]
name = "aedttest"
authors = [
    {name = "Maksim Beliaev", email = "beliaev.m.s@gmail.com"},
    {name = "Bo Yang", email = "boy@kth.se"},
]
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = ["License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License"]
dynamic = ["version", "description"]

dependencies = [
    "pyaedt==0.4.7",
    "Django==3.2.8",
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "black==21.9b0",
    "pre-commit==2.15.0",
    "mypy==0.910",
    "pytest==6.2.5",
    "pytest-cov==3.0.0",
]

deploy = [
    "flit==3.4.0",
]
```

to install core dependencies you run:

```
pip install .
```

if you need test(develop) environment (we use `test` because it is a name defined in .toml file, you can use any):

```
pip install .[test]
```

To install from Wheel:

```
pip install C:\git\aedt-testing\dist\aedttest-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl[test]
```

Comment: `pip install .` doesn't just download the dependencies, it *installs* them, as well as the actual project itself.

Comment: true, but maybe this answer will be anyway helpful for somebody. I find limited info on pyproject.toml file

Comment: This answer was certainly helpful for me - I couldn't find anywhere else the 'dependencies' list under project was specified, and that's what is needed for pip to install other packages needed at run time.

Comment: This is a great example, and like `@A. Rose` I couldn't find much in the way of examples. However I have one question/problem remaining (and I accept that I may be searching for a tree while stumbling through a forest): how do I install the `project.optional-dependencies` from your example using `pip`?

Comment: Ha! Answered my own question (I found that dang tree!). From [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4340) I deduced that installing an `[project.optional-dependencies]` is done like so: `python -m pip install .[dependency-name]`.

Comment: If you run Zsh, run `pip install -e '.[tests]'`, if you get the `zsh: no matches found: .[tests]` error.

Comment: What about listing a local package in the toml `dependencies`. There's a package I need that is not on pypi and I have included its repo in my project. I've tried `"/packagedirectory"` and other similar syntax but none of these are PEP 508 compliant and thus raise an error. Hints?

Comment: Never mind, I came up with a solution to local dependencies with "relative" absolute paths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75630599/9403538).

Comment: @NostraDavid On zsh you can run `pip install -e .'[tests]'` with the dot outside the quotes and that should work, at least it works for me with zsh in iTerm2 on my Mac.

Answer (score 11):

pip supports [installing pyproject.toml dependencies](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#pep-517-and-518-support) natively.

> As of version 10.0, pip supports projects declaring dependencies that are required at install time using a pyproject.toml file, in the form described in PEP 518. When building a project, pip will install the required dependencies locally, and make them available to the build process. Furthermore, from version 19.0 onwards, pip supports projects specifying the build backend they use in pyproject.toml, in the form described in PEP 517.

From the project's root, use pip's [local project](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#local-project-installs) install:

```
python -m pip install .
```

Comment: That command doesn't just download the dependencies, it *installs* them, as well as the actual project itself.

Comment: is there a way to point to some pyproject.toml file outside of a local project?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the dependencies to a `requirements.txt` and use `pip download` afterwards:

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt
pip download -r  requirements.txt
```

Comment: The question is about using the pyproject.toml file directly, not generating a requirements.txt file.

Comment: The OP said they are using Poetry. So this is the answer to do it. If you really want to have only one command, the answer would be: You cannot.

Comment: The OP asks specifically about using pip to download the dependencies directly using the pyproject.toml file - which pip can do (as it can interpret the given pyproject.toml file). The poetry export is not needed.

Comment: The OP said they are **not** using poetry. But I agree it is confusing, because [tag:python-poetry] is tagged.

Comment: Upvoting this.
This is not a perfect solution, far from it, but it does allow for easy extraction of requirements *without* installing the project itself

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is looking for a simple answer with only `pip`, this worked for me:

```bash
pip install . && pip uninstall -y <your-project>
```

E.g. I have a `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
ADD pyproject.toml /workspaces/my-awesome-project/

RUN pip install . && \
    pip uninstall -y my-awesome-project && \
    rm pyproject.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the dependencies you can do the following:

1. `cd` into the directory where the `pyproject.toml` file is contained
2. `pip download .`