# Can I use pyproject.toml with pip?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pep517

I want to replace multiple projects where I work, that use `setup.py` with `pyproject.toml`. I couldn't find a whole lot details about `pyproject.toml` and all I could find seems to use poetry.

I don't really want to replace our use of pip since introducing a new tool to a lot of people could be quite the headache...

If there is way to use pip, could someone please show how to do so or how the file should look like? I tried searching in github for some examples but all I found was with poetry use.

Thanks.

Comment: They are independent of each other. You put your tool configs in there like mypy  or pylint

Comment: although, you can put deps inside https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408719/download-dependencies-declared-in-pyproject-toml-using-pip

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Also the link you sent also has an example of a full pyproject file which is exactly what I needed!!