# Specifying local relative dependency in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

I have the following project structure:

```
root
  - sample/
    - src/
    - tests/
    - pyproject.toml
  - libs/
    - lol/
      - src/
      - tests/
      - pyproject.toml
```

I'd like to specify `lol` as a dependency for `sample` in `sample/pyproject.toml`. How it can be done? I've tried:

```
dependencies = [ 
   "lol @ file://libs/lol"
]
```

But it gives me:

```
ValueError: non-local file URIs are not supported on this platform: 'file://libs/lol'
```

and that's ok however I cannot put absolute path here since this is going to be shared code. Same for `file://./lib/lol`.

What can be done about that? Can I use env variables here, or some placeholders? I don't want to use tools like poetry.

Comment: In `file://` (2 slashes) `libs` is a host. For a local file it must be `file:/` (1 slash) or `file:///` (3 slashes). Not sure if it's possible to set a relative path; try `file:/./libs/name`. If doesn't work the only way is to have a full path: `file:///path/to/libs/name`

Comment: Thanks @phd. `/` gives `configuration error: project.dependencies[{data__dependencies_x}] must be pep508` and `///` `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/libs/lol'` so I suppose I cannot be relative.

Comment: `file:./` might work for relative paths?  Depends on pythonk though I guess.

Comment: You might want to use additional "dev workflow tool", such as PDM, Hatch, or Poetry to handle such cases. Putting relative paths (especially in parent directories) in packaging metadata is not really a use case that is supported.

Answer (score 5):

I have been searching far and wide for a solution to relative path packages in the toml dependencies. This solution is admittedly hacky, but it's the best I have so far. Basically, I use git hooks to modify the toml file on each machine with its respective absolute path. See below:

###### My `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["rotor", "stator"]

[project]
version = "1.0.0"
name = "RTTS"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
# ADD DEPENDENCIES HERE

# more stuff as needed...
```

Note the important part is the comment identifier `# ADD DEPENDENCIES HERE`

###### My `toml_mod.py` file (located next to `pyproject.toml`):

```
from pathlib import Path

PATH = Path(__file__).parents[0].resolve()
DEPENDENCIES = f"['celery', 'daqhats@{PATH.as_uri()}/daqhats', 'eventlet', 'Flask', 'Flask-SocketIO', 'redis', 'RPi.GPIO']"
CONFIG = []

with open(f"{PATH}/pyproject.toml", 'rb') as f:
    line_bytes = f.readline()
    while line_bytes:
        if line_bytes.decode().strip() == "# ADD DEPENDENCIES HERE":
            CONFIG.append(f"dependencies = {DEPENDENCIES}\n".encode())
        else:
            CONFIG.append(line_bytes)
        line_bytes = f.readline()

with open("pyproject.toml", 'wb') as f:
    for line_bytes in CONFIG:
        f.write(line_bytes)
```

You would replace the `daqhats` package on line 4 with your local package file structure. The loop then finds the comment identifier in the toml file and replaces it with the specific absolute path on the respective host.

###### My basic `post-receive` git hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)

cd /home/pi/Projects/Alpha
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master

python toml_mod.py
```

Note that I fetch and reset to another directory, overwriting any changes made in that directory with the master version.

For me, I develop on Windows and push to a bunch of embedded systems. I use git hooks to automatically push to each embedded system on my development network after commits on my Windows development machine. For me, the `post-receive` hook is for deployment, and I never end up working in this deployment directory (in my case `/home/pi/Projects/Alpha` on the embedded device). This means the only merge conflict overwritten when doing a hard reset to `origin/master` is the previous toml modification from the last deployment. Each embedded system has a bare master repo on it and it's own `post-receive` hook. This makes deployment to each device easy, and the respective path for that device is used rather than some hard coded one. It's a workaround.

Your mileage may vary, and you may have to play with different hook files (i.e. `post-<your git event here>` based on your development flow and usage. If the toml is to be modified in a working dev's directory, you may have to get tricky with not overwriting all their conflicts, or just doing the toml modification on the initial clone and never again (perhaps there's a `post-clone` hook). Also, the hook has to be a script the host OS can use (linux bash in my case).

###### NOTE:

There is the `tomllib` library in Python 3.11, but it does not write to toml files (it only reads them). There are packages that will write to toml files, but I am specifically sticking to the standard library in this answer because no dependencies have been installed yet. The only thing this answer assumes is that the host has Python and a git repo. Installation of dependencies comes after the toml file modification. For deployment, this can be done in the very same `post-receive` hook with `pip install /path/to/pyproject.toml/directory` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for that, pretty impressive. But it's indeed, hacky, not what I'm looking for. I feel like with it I'm introducing a kind of a technical debt. This way it's better for me to store dependencies in `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn your file path from relative to absolute by using a `$PROJECT_ROOT` env var and injecting it into the path itself. ie.:

```
dependencies = [ 
   "lol @ file:///${PROJECT_ROOT}/libs/lol"
]
```

If you're using `pdm`, it will inject this variable for you. Otherwise, you'll need to assign it yourself. That can be done several ways but it depends on your project and is probably out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks. What's `pdm`?

Comment: @Opal It's a package manager for Python: https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now I recall it. I even considered using it during the refactor.

Comment: `uv` supports this, too: https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/pull/640

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) for that.

Your `pyproject.toml` would look like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "Sample"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My Sample"
authors = ["Opal <opal@example.com>"]
packages = [{ include = "Sample", from = 'src' }]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10,<3.11" 
numpy = "^1.23.1"
lol = { path = "libs/lol/", develop = true, extras = ['my_extra'] }


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Two years ago, Poetry was the only tool that allowed transitive local relative dependencies, i.e. in your case it allows the Lol project to have local relative dependencies on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we did a lot to remove poetry from our codebase ;)

Comment: May I ask why? I am thinking about introducing it to my org (for this very reason) and I'd like to know the cons. @Opal

Comment: sorry for the late answer. The main problem is that it wasn't something easy to use/setup by python users (but not developers). I mean data science people specifically. The other problem is that we probably had it set incorrectly - a single big ball of dependency mud project. Right I'd probably give it a try once again.

Comment: @Opal I guess you did know/have `poetry-core` at the time. If your users have `pip`, that may be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Like you already mentioned, you can define local dependencies like this:

```ini
[project]
dependencies = [
    "lol @ file://libs/lol"
]
```

If you wan't to make them relative to your project root you can use the `root:uri` context. But you can do way more with this. I recommend reading the [hatch documentation](https://hatch.pypa.io/dev/config/context/) on context formatting for more detail.

```ini
[project]
dependencies = [
    "lol @ {root:uri}/libs/lol"
]
```

This *should* work across build tools. But if you are using hatch, you need to set an additional value. See the [documentation](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#allowing-direct-references).

```ini
[tool.hatch.metadata]
allow-direct-references = true

[project]
dependencies = [
    "lol @ {root:uri}/libs/lol"
]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does *not* across build tools. I just tried it with setuptools and it complained about the dependency needing to be pep508.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the dependencies in `pyproject.toml`, mark them as [dynamic](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata):

```ini
[project]
# Replace this:
dependencies = [
    ...
]
# With:
dynamic = ["dependencies"]
```

Then create a minimal `setup.py` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77736663/3372061):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import setup

# This is where you add any fancy path resolution to the local lib:
local_path: str = (Path(__file__).parent / "somewhere").as_uri()

setup(
    install_requires=[
        f"package-name @ {local_path}",
        # other dependencies...
    ]
)
```

Using `setup.py` alongside `pyproject.toml` is mentioned in the [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html) (albeit in a somewhat different context).