# How to install local package with transitive dependencies?

Tags: python, pip

I have two python projects under the same root, after `tree` it looks as follows:

```
libs
└── lol-pandas
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── requirements-dev.txt
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── src
    │   └── lol
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── pandas
    │           ├── __init__.py
    └── tests
        └── __init__.py
```

and:

```
batch
└── lol_integration
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── requirements-dev.txt
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── src
        └── lol_integration
            └── __init__.py
```

In `lol-integration/requirements.txt` I have:

```
../../libs/lol-pandas/
```

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in `lol-integration` I'm getting a dependency to `lol_pandas` and it works, but can I have the dependencies that `lol-pandas` have - namely the dependencies from `lol-pandas/requirements.txt` - installed too? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe try defining requirements in dependencies of your pyproject.toml file

Comment: @JakePeralta, thanks but I can't. I cannot define a relative dependency in `pyproject.toml` and want to have them in a single place. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159453/specifying-local-relative-dependency-in-pyproject-toml).