# how to let pip install dependencies of my current source package without actually install the package?

Tags: python, pip

according to many suggestion we are deprecating the requirements.txt So now developers are purely based on dependencies described in setup.py and pyproject.toml (if one want to build it).

Previously, one can just do `pip install -r requirements.txt`

However, since the requirements.txt will be removed. How would one do this step easily.
Many developers do not actually want to install with `-e .` because they may have production version in the system. One would just want to quickly spin up with proper dependencies and start to edit in their IDE.

Comment: How can you use the package if you are not installing it (even for dev purposes) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the answer you are looking for but it is very important to stress it here: you should develop in compartimented environments. Be it a venv or a conda is a matter of taste as long as it’s pure Python.

As long as you do that it’s perfectly safe to use:

```
Pip install -e .
```

If you don’t need to install the package because you simply want to build the documentation or run the test, have a look to nox and tox they will create these venv for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408719/download-dependencies-declared-in-pyproject-toml-using-pip). tldr; you can't just using `pip`. There are issues that are trying to integrate that functionality to `pip`, for example: [11440](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11440).

## Solution using `flit`

If one option could be to change build backend, you could change the build backend to [flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/pyproject_toml.html), which supports this functionality, as shown [here](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/cmdline.html#cmdoption-flit-install-only-deps), by using the command `flit install --only-deps`. That command will only install the dependencies of the package you're working on, but not the package itself.

## EDIT with a suggestion

I would suggest that you use virtual environments to be able to experiment faster and have isolated development environments. One tool that I use to manage my virtual environments is `pipenv`. This tool has the functionality to reset environments easily and install all dependencies described in another file, `Pipfile`. I suggest this in case you don't mind versioning another file. If you don't want an extra file (probably the reason you deprecated `requirements.txt` in the first place), you can use the solution I described with `flit`.

Answer (score 0):

I use poetry (https://python-poetry.org/). As others have said you should always develop in a virtual environment, that way `pip install -e .` is perfectly safe as the package and all it's requirements are isolated (and you can test the package knowing it's environment only contains what's included in setup.py / pyproject.toml or requirements.txt). Not doing this has always run the risk that you think your package works, you try and install it elsewhere and find you were using a package that you didn't declare. Creating a virtual environment is easy - my steps are:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/acticate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Poetry automates this, it manages both package versions and the project's virtual environment. So you can check a project out of git, run `poetry install` and it creates the venv and installs your package and it's dependencies.