# requirements.txt with a -e flag requires git credentials

Tags: python, git, pip

### Setup

A Python project I just cloned has a requirements.txt file with this as the following line:

```
-e git+https://github.com/<my_org>/shared.git@v0.3.21#egg=shared
```

I've never seen this before, but after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install) I see that -e basically means that `shared` is another project that belongs to `my_org` that I might be editing locally. (I'm not, but I do have access to that repository.)

### Problem

The actual problem that I'm encountering is that when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` I'm prompted to enter my git username and password. This doesn't work for me, even though I can successfully log into git with the same credentials. My organization uses 2FA so I'm not sure how that'd work anyway.

Just guessing, I tried changing to the URL to the `git@github...` address, which is what I've successfully done in the past when cloning repositories, but it appears that `git+https` is required in this case.

### Question

What is the recommended approach to managing credentials w/ 2FA and what might I do to proceed installing my requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [pip's install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git) documentation  could use **ssh** instead of **https**:

```
-e git+ssh://github.com/<my_org>/shared.git@v0.3.21#egg=shared
```

Note that you will need to have proper [ssh keys configured](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) for your account.