# How to debug a python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm creating my first package and I can not figure out how to create a simple `test.py` file to debug my code.

Consider the following file structure.

```
|--MyPackage
  |--test.py
  |--PackageName
      |--__init__.py
      |--module.py
```

Inside  `test.py` I have: `from .src.module import SomeClass`

And of course this gives me the dreaded **"attempted relative import with no known parent package"** message.

I know I could just install the package and then import it with `from PackageName.module import SomeClass` but then I'm using the code installed on my system and not the code that I am actively editing.

There has got to be some kind of standard way for testing and debugging a package right? Despite all the searching I've done, I can't seem to find any kind of solution.

I'm running `test.py` with `python3 test.py`

If it's helpful, here is a screenshot of my actual project folder structure:[image]

Comment: Are you running `test.py` as a standalone Python script (`python3 test.py`), or as a submodule of a package (`python3 -m MyPackage.test`)? It looks like you want to do the latter. Relative imports don't make sense with the former.

Comment: I'm using `python3 test.py`

Comment: Is `MyPackage` supposed to be a package? Also re: "but then I'm using the code installed on my system and not the code that I am actively editing", you may be looking for [When would the -e, --editable option be useful with pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install)

Comment: The -e option is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. I would still like to better understand python imports and why my implementation doesn't work. Know of any resources that can explain this to me simply?

Comment: If you haven't read it already, the official documentation is the first place to go. The sections on [Modules & Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) (especially sections 6.1.2 and 6.4) and [the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) cover just about everything there is to know. These SO questions are also good reads: [Importing files from different folder](/questions/4383571/), [Relative imports for the billionth time](/questions/14132789/) (and links therein), [Difference between a Python module and a Python package?](/questions/7948494/).

Comment: The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the literature on the import structure for python scripts, I managed to find another way using PyCharm.

1. Install the python package with `pip install <package>`
2. Navigate to the package and open the folder with PyCharm
3. On the top right corner open the dropdown and select *Edit Configurations*
4. Choose the '+' icon and select python
5. In the *Configuration* tab click the arrow next to *Script path:* and select *Module name* and enter the module name next to it

You're now running the package at it's entry point and can use the python debug functionality.