# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anonymizer.anonymization'

Tags: python, blur, privacy, face, anonymize

Getting this error:
(blur) D:\anonymizer-master\anonymizer\bin>python anonymize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "anonymize.py", line 20, in <module>
from anonymizer.anonymization import Anonymizer

```
By Running this file:
import argparse

from anonymizer.anonymization import Anonymizer
from anonymizer.detection import Detector, download_weights, get_weights_path
from anonymizer.obfuscation import Obfuscator


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Anonymize faces and license plates in a series of images.')
    parser.add_argument('--input', required=True,
                        metavar='/path/to/input_folder',
                        help='Path to a folder that contains the images that should be anonymized. '
                             'Images can be arbitrarily nested in subfolders and will still be found.')
    parser.add_argument('--image-output', required=True,
                        metavar='/path/to/output_foler',
                        help='Path to the folder the anonymized images should be written to. '
                             'Will mirror the folder structure of the input folder.')
    parser.add_argument('--weights', required=True,
                        metavar='/path/to/weights_foler',
                        help='Path to the folder where the weights are stored. If no weights with the '
                             'appropriate names are found they will be downloaded automatically.')
    parser.add_argument('--image-extensions', required=False, default='jpg,png',
                        metavar='"jpg,png"',
                        help='Comma-separated list of file types that will be anonymized')
    parser.add_argument('--face-threshold', type=float, required=False, default=0.3,
                        metavar='0.3',
                        help='Detection confidence needed to anonymize a detected face. '
                             'Must be in [0.001, 1.0]')
    parser.add_argument('--plate-threshold', type=float, required=False, default=0.3,
                        metavar='0.3',
                        help='Detection confidence needed to anonymize a detected license plate. '
                             'Must be in [0.001, 1.0]')
    parser.add_argument('--write-detections', dest='write_detections', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--no-write-detections', dest='write_detections', action='store_false')
    parser.set_defaults(write_detections=True)
    parser.add_argument('--obfuscation-kernel', required=False, default='21,2,9',
                        metavar='kernel_size,sigma,box_kernel_size',
                        help='This parameter is used to change the way the blurring is done. '
```

Comment: @kmkurn yes i did u can see at the top of the code

Comment: @kmkurn still same error.  i prefer u can try at your end. here is the link of the folder https://github.com/understand-ai/anonymizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because Python cannot find the `anonymizer.anonymization` module in `PYTHONPATH`. So, a solution is to install the module because thankfully the repo has a functional `setup.py`. Run the below code (tested on Ubuntu) from the `anonymizer-master`'s parent directory.

```bash
pip install anonymizer-master
python anonymizer-master/anonymizer/bin/anonymize.py
```

The first command will also install the repo's dependencies. If you plan to edit the files in the repo, use `pip install -e anonymizer-master` (notice the `-e` option) to [install in editable mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install).

Comment: i appreciate your comment

Comment: getting this error 
File "anonymizer-master/anonymize.py", line 104, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\faizan.afzal\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 214, in __init__
    .format(value, type(value))), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '3.0' with type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'

Comment: THIS COMMAND IM RUNNING.
python anonymize.py --input images --image-output images --weights weights_face_v1.0.0.pb