# What is the best way to organize Python import paths for multiple but independent projects?

Tags: python, path, python-import

Say I have three projects A, B and C in my home directory, all written mainly in Python:

```bash
.
├── project_A
│   ├── data
│   ├── plot
│   ├── result
│   └── run.py
├── project_B
│   ├── data
│   ├── plot
│   ├── result
│   └── run.py
└── project_C
    ├── data
    ├── plot
    ├── result
    └── run.py
```

They all have a similar structures: `data`, `result` and `plot` are all directories that contain various scripts.
My question is, if I were to export the paths for each of the projects into `PYTHONPATH` like:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/project_A
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/project_B:${PYTHONPATH}
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/project_C:${PYTHONPATH}
```

then there will be conflicts/confusions, because all three projects have `data`, `plot` as well as `result`, when I do `from data.script import function`, I am not sure if am importing from project A, B or C.

Given that the three projects are **independent**, can I do the following:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}
```

and in project A, for example, I imagine that I can safely do:

```py
from project_A.data.script import function
```

Will anything unexpected happen when I put my home directory into `PYTHONPATH`?
Is there anything I need to be careful with?
Is this a good practice at all?
If not, what should I be doing instead?
Thanks!

Comment: No, good practice would be to create a python package and import your modules just like you would any other third party library without messing with the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, but I need to work on those projects, plus these projects also contain other types of files, like `.xlsx` and so on.

Comment: Perhaps I should make a directory called `projects` and put A, B and C inside it. Then in `.bashrc` I can do `export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/projects`?

Comment: @zyy https://stackoverflow.com/a/35064498/152043 you can create a venv (virtual env) and then install each of your modules into it in editable mode, allowing you to edit them in place and for them to see the changes you make between them. editable mode basically slaps them into the pip package repo as a symlink back to wherever the package is.

Comment: @MichaelSpeer I tried to use `pip install -e` with a dummy `setup.py`, but the installation failed. Seems like `pip` wants a more detailed instruction. So I end up making a directory `projects` in my home and export it to `PYTHONPATH`.