# How to update custom package version?

Tags: python, git, pipenv, python-packaging

I am trying to create a python package that I can reuse in other projects. I did follow this tutorial: [Create Your Custom, private Python Package That You Can PIP Install From Your Git Repository](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-your-custom-python-package-that-you-can-pip-install-from-your-git-repository-f90465867893).

It works but when I update the code of my package and then try to update the package on a project that uses this package, it does not update.

So I have a git repo with my package at https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage with following files:

- `myCustomPackage/functions.py` with the following function:

```
def say_foo():
    print('Foo')
```

- A `setup.py` file with:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='myCustomPackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='Vincent2303',
    description='Testing installation of Package',
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license='MIT',
    packages=['myCustomPackage'],
    install_requires=[],
)
```

Then I created a test project, with:

- A `main.py` file:

```
from myCustomPackage import functions

functions.say_foo()
```

- A Pipfile (I did `pipenv shell` then `pipenv install git+https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git#egg=myCustomPackage`):

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
mycustompackage = {git = "https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git"}

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

At this point it works well, I can use `say_foo`.

Then I added a new function `say_bar` on myCustomPackage (in `myCustomPackage/functions.py`). I did increment version from `0.0.1` to `0.0.2` in `setup.py`. I did commit and push.

In my project that uses myCustomPackage I did run `pipenv install`, I expect pip to check version, detect that there is a new version and update it but it does not. I can't use `say_bar` (I get error: `AttributeError: module 'myCustomPackage.functions' has no attribute 'say_bar'`)

I tried as well to re run `pipenv install git+https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git#egg=myCustomPackage`. It does not update.

**How can I update the version of `myCustomPackage` in projects that uses this package ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pipenv` works like `pip` in general, the issue here is you're saying "yeah, get mycustompackage from that repo, I don't care which version", for which the `pip` remedy is the [`#egg=` URL fragment](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments):

```
pip install https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git#egg=myCustomPackage==0.0.2
```

, i.e. tell `pip` that you're about to get a requirement `myCustomPackage==0.0.2` from this git URL, and that's your requirement.

You could/should also use a distinct [ref](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#git) instead of the implicit "HEAD of the default branch"; if you have tagged your new version on Git (as you should do for released versions so it's easy to see what code has contributed to it), use that tag, e.g. if the tag is `v0.0.2`,

```
https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git@v0.0.2#egg=myCustomPackage==0.0.2
```

but you could just as well use a commit ID (this *just so* happens to be the ID for [your 0.0.3 commit](https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage/commit/ff65083ff85d041337c62dc83a84bbc59ad18d8e)):

```
https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git@ff65083ff#egg=myCustomPackage==0.0.3
```

Finally, translating this to your `pipenv` file, try

```
mycustompackage = {git = "https://github.com/vincent2303/myCustomPackage.git@ff65083ff#egg=myCustomPackage==0.0.3"}
```

Comment: thank you it works :) Do you know if there is a way to always use the latest version when I run pipenv install ? For instance if it is on `0.0.7` and last version on project is `0.0.4` it will automatically update to version `0.0.7` ?

Comment: The simplest way is to `pip uninstall myCustomPackage` before running `pipenv install` so the machinery doesn't think the requirement is already met. However, that's a bad idea in general; you _do_ want to know which version you're running. While developing your library, and/or a thing using that library, use [`--editable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353319/51685) instead.