# Importing modules from other directory

Tags: python, import, module, modulenotfounderror

Is there any recommended/opinionated way of importing modules within the same projects without hacks like `sys.path.append` or exporting `PYTHONPATH` with paths to neighbour directories?

I am trying to add some tests to my app, nothing extraordinary.

```
app/
  - __init__.py
  - app_to_be_tested.py
tests/
  - test_app_to_be_tested.py
```

How am I supposed to do that in most 'pythonic' way - either one the hacks above, build a package for my own code that will never be imported by any other app or restructure directory topology?

Any advice appreciated.

edit

`app.py`

```
def some_func():
   return 'abcd'
```

`test_app.py`

```
from ..app import app

def test_some_func():
    assert app.some_func() == 'abcd'
```

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

edit 2

had a change to get back to it

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── inner
│       └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_app.py
```

content of app/inner/__init__.py

```
def func_from_inner():
    return 'from inner'
```

app/app.py

```
from inner import func_from_inner

def some_func():
    return func_from_inner()
```

running the code from root dir results in ModuleNotFound (how come?)

```
 python3 -m app.app
 ...
 File "/redacted/app/app.py", line 11, in <module>
 from inner import func_from_inner ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inner'
```

running it the same way from the app directory works

when I change the import in app/app.py to

```
from .inner import func_from_inner
```

it works from the root dir

sys.path does contain the root project dir, doesn't it mean it should import everything recursively?

in addition to that, running python3 app/app.py results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/redacted/app/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .inner import func_from_inner
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work
edited question

Comment: Should be explain how it works [Python imports](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for opinionated - here is something that works for me based on working with someone experienced in python - based on this question/answers - [When would the -e, --editable option be useful with pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35064426)

set up a virtual env and install your app there:

```bash
test -d .venv || python -m venv .venv # make sure all venv pkgs are available
. .venv/bin/activate # or as appropriate for your os
pip install -e .
python tests/test_app.py
```

then in your test just import as normal:

```py
from app import app

def test_some_func():
    print('running test: test_some_func')
    assert app.some_func() == 'abcd'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_some_func()
```

complete demo here - https://github.com/alexanderankin/demo-so76882111