# how do I pip uninstall package beginning with special character '-e ...'?

Tags: python, pip

pip freeze:

```
  ...  
  howdoi==1.1.9
  **-e git+https://github.com/fredzannarbor/howdoi21.git@0efdd53947bb233d529225db30aba2e1e4e2cc6e#egg=howdoi21**
  html5lib==0.999
...
```

How do I delete the package whose name begins '-e ...'? I tried

```
 pip uninstall '\-e git+https://github.com/fredzannarbor/howdoi21.git@0efdd53947bb233d529225db30aba2e1e4e2cc6e#egg=howdoi21 
'
Invalid requirement: '\-e git+https://github.com/fredzannarbor/howdoi21.git@0efdd53947bb233d529225db30aba2e1e4e2cc6e#egg=howdoi21'
It looks like a path. Does it exist ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip uninstall howdoi21`

- Usually the 'egg=[PackageName][-dev][-version]' part contains the project name.
- If the github repository was not deleted, you can find the project name from `setup.py` file.
- [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e)