# How to remove in development mode a python package's dependencies with pip (note not the same as removing the package)?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

Let's say I am working on a python package. How can I revert a `pip install -e .[dev]`?
That is, something along the lines of `python setup.py develop --uninstall` but with pip.

Thanks in advance.

## Edit

This question has been identified as similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e), but it's not. My question is a bit more fundamental.

Comment: `pip uninstall <package-name>`

Comment: @phd  No, that is a different issue, likely due to [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4438) in earlier version of pip. Manual removal of files should *not* be required in the usual case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e)

Comment: @CharlieParker No, that is a different issue, and this OP has already edited to clarify that! Linked question is about pip failing to remove the files associated with an editable install, this question is about pip failing to uninstall the dependencies. The linked question was associated with a bug in pip. See the comment already above yours.

Comment: @wim thanks from the clarification, seems the title needs an serious edit then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `pip` command to uninstall a package and also uninstall dangling dependencies.  You have to uninstall one-by-one by checking in `pip freeze` output.

To uninstall an editable install, you'll need to know the name of the  package (check in the `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file) and then you can remove the usual way:

```
pip uninstall somepackage
```

Comment: I see. In fact, and although I did not mention I was thinking about the process of uninstalling dependencies as well. I am glad you mentioned it. Also `python setup.py develop --uninstall` doesn't remove any dependencies either. Thanks.

Comment: How is your answer different from the ones here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e

Comment: Unrelated. That post is about removing the files of an editable install itself. This question is about dangling dependencies.