# How does one check if conda develop installed my project/packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

**How do I see the packages that I've installed in development mode?**
I tried `conda list` but it didn't show anything familiar.

I ran `conda develop .` and it seems it installed it:

```
(automl-meta-learning) brandomiranda~/automl-meta-learning/automl ❯ conda develop .
path exists, skipping /Users/brandomiranda/automl-meta-learning/automl
completed operation for: /Users/brandomiranda/automl-meta-learning/automl
```

however, I get errors when I run my scripts:

```
(automl-meta-learning) brandomiranda~/automl-meta-learning/automl/automl/meta_optimizers ❯ python differentiable_SGD.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "differentiable_SGD.py", line 8, in <module>
    from automl.utils.torch_utils import helloworld
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'automl.utils'
```

but when I do conda list I don't see anything I recognize:

```
(automl-meta-learning) brandomiranda~/automl-meta-learning/automl/automl/meta_optimizers ❯ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/brandomiranda/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.13.2           py37hb5b8e2f_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
conda                     4.8.1                    py37_0
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0
cryptography              2.8              py37ha12b0ac_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
dbus                      1.13.12              h90a0687_0
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_1
ipython                   7.11.1           py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h54f8f79_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0
mkl                       2019.4                      233
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1
ninja                     1.9.0            py37h04f5b5a_0
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h7241aed_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37h6575580_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_3
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    7.0.0            py37h4655f20_0
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0
psutil                    5.6.7            py37h1de35cc_0
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2
pyrsistent                0.15.6           py37h1de35cc_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.6                h359304d_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-graphviz           0.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13
pytorch                   1.4.0                   py3.7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pyyaml                    5.2              py37h1de35cc_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37h0a44026_0
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                44.0.0                   py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.30.1               ha441bb4_0
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0
torchvision               0.5.0                  py37_cpu    pytorch
torchviz                  0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_0
tqdm                      4.41.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
urllib3                   1.25.7                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

anyone know whats going on or at least where the packages I've installed in development mode would show up?

---

Note that my scripts work now after installing and uninstalling using `conda develop -u .` but I still don't know how to display if the packages/projects in development mode are installed or not.

Comment: I've tried what this suggests and it does not work. I conda develop . my package and then when I run the python interpreter and try to import it the import fails. Why? Nearly identical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467310/how-does-one-see-all-the-packages-that-have-been-installed-in-developer-mode-wit

Comment: btw if you want to uninstall something that was installed with conda develop do `conda develop -u .` or `conda develop -u <path>`

Comment: might be helpful: `conda install conda-build` before running `conda develop `psth2pkg`

Answer (score 14):

If you look carefully after running `conda develop .` (where the `setup.py` file is) you will notice that the command outputs the following:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop .
added /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
completed operation for: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

if you then check the `sys.path` python has then you can that new path has been added:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python37.zip
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/automl-meta-learning/automl
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/higher
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

you can confirm this by removing it and printing the contents of `sys.path`:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
uninstalled: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

check sys path again:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python37.zip
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/automl-meta-learning/automl
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/higher
```

now it's gone!

Also, note that conda or python (not sure which) also adds the current path always. This is important to note because when I did import tests outside of the repo I was working it wasn't working but it was inside the repo which seemed very mysterious which I can only attribute to that.

---

## Addendum

to check python sys.path from terminal run that command as a string with python cmd:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

even better:

```
python -c "import sys; [print(p) for p in sys.path]"
```

if you want an alias:

```
alias pypath='python -c "import sys; [print(p) for p in sys.path]"'
```

put it in your `.zshrc`.

---

## Old answer

Honestly the only way I know is to just try to install it again. It usually says its there already:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop .
path exists, skipping /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
completed operation for: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

if it says it's there already but your scripts still don't work just try installing and uninstalling:

```
conda develop -u .
```

the output should be something like this:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
uninstalled: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

then again try to install it in develop/developing/developer mode:

```
conda develop .
```

output looks something like this:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
uninstalled: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

where . can be substituted to a path to the root of your project (for me it's where setup.py is at).

---

Note:

An additional test is to try to uninstall it twice. The second time it should complain:

```
(importtest) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
uninstalled: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
(importtest) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
conda.pth does not contain path: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
package not installed via conda develop
```

---

Fyi: how uninstall in pip editable mode: [How to uninstall editable packages with pip (installed with -e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e)

Comment: might be helpful: `conda install conda-build` before running `conda develop `psth2pkg`