# How does one see all the packages that have been installed in developer mode with conda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I did `conda list` but I can't see what I am looking for. Are conda packages installed with `conda developed .` not shown?

```
# packages in environment at /Users/pinocchio/anaconda3/envs/myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
appnope                   0.1.0           py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
c-ares                    1.15.0            h1de35cc_1001  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
cairo                     1.14.12              hc4e6be7_4  
certifi                   2020.4.5.1               py37_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
cryptography              2.8              py37ha12b0ac_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h5d5b041_1  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h1de35cc_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h2098e52_0  
graphviz                  2.40.1               hefbbd9a_2  
grpcio                    1.16.1           py37h044775b_1  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hb8d4a28_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.9                        py_1  
importlib-metadata        1.6.0            py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        1.6.0                         0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
ipykernel                 5.2.0            py37h43977f1_1    conda-forge
ipython                   7.13.0           py37hc8dfbb8_2    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
jedi                      0.16.0           py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.2                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.0.7                      py_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libprotobuf               3.11.4               hd9629dc_0  
libsodium                 1.0.17               h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h9aa3819_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h0b31af3_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_0  
ninja                     1.9.0            py37h04f5b5a_0  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h7241aed_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37h6575580_1  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h1de35cc_0  
pandoc                    2.9.2                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
pango                     1.42.4               h060686c_0  
parso                     0.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5           py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
pillow                    6.2.1            py37hb68e598_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1  
pixman                    0.38.0               h1de35cc_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37h0a44026_0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                   py_1001    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h9bfed18_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.7           hc70fcce_0_cpython  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python-graphviz           0.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.4.0                   py3.7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37h0a44026_0  
readline                  8.0                  h1de35cc_0  
requests                  2.23.0                   py37_0  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                46.1.1                   py37_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0  
soupsieve                 2.0                        py_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               ha441bb4_0  
tensorboard               2.0.0              pyhb38c66f_1  
terminado                 0.8.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
torchvision               0.2.1                      py_2    soumith
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h9bfed18_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.43.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.9              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37h1de35cc_1  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.3.2                h6de7cb9_2    conda-forge
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

utils or something like that should be there but its not.

---

Update:

I've tried what this suggests and it does not work. I conda develop . my package and then when I run the python interpreter and try to import it the import fails. Why?

```
>>> import my_pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'
```

---

I also tried to install it with pip `pip install -e` and it doesn't find my package either after I go to the interpreter and try to import it. Why is that?

Comment: Something would be shown in the `build` column of the table for `conda develop .` packages. Are you sure you're running the right Python interpreter? What's the output of `print(sys.path)`? Are you sure you used the right `pip` if you have multiple environments/Pythons installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully after running `conda develop .` (where the `setup.py` file is) you will notice that the command outputs the following:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop .
added /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
completed operation for: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

if you then check the `sys.path` python has then you can that new path has been added:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python37.zip
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/automl-meta-learning/automl
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/higher
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

you can confirm this by removing it and printing the contents of `sys.path`:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ conda develop -u .
uninstalled: /Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/ultimate-utils/uutils
```

check sys path again:

```
(automl) brandBrandoParetoopareto~/ultimate-utils/uutils $ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python37.zip
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/anaconda3/envs/automl/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/automl-meta-learning/automl
/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/higher
```

now it's gone!

Also, note that conda or python (not sure which) also adds the current path always. This is important to note because when I did import tests outside of the repo I was working it wasn't working but it was inside the repo which seemed very mysterious which I can only attribute to that.

---

## Addendum

to check python sys.path from terminal run that command as a string with python cmd:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

even better:

```
python -c "import sys; [print(p) for p in sys.path]"
```

---

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903590/1601580