# reverse pip install "-e" option

Tags: python, pip, package

While developing a package I installed it through `pip install -e .`

Now when I `pip uninstall myPackage` I get

```
Found existing installation: myPackage 0.1.2
Can't uninstall 'myPackage'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

with `pip show myPackage` I get:

```
Location: /mnt/home/aerijman/scripts/myPackage
```

I don't want to delete the path. How do I uninstall it?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall+editable+package

Comment: if you are interested in uninstall (packages in development/editable mode) try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e

Comment: the different options I know work sometimes are: `python setup.py develop -u`, `pip uninstall library`, `pip uninstall -e .` and `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the project's name is `MyProject`, there should be a `MyProject.egg-link` file in the `site-packages` directory for this Python interpreter. Running the command `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m site` should help you figure out the possible location of this directory. Find the directory, find the `MyProject.egg-link` file, delete the file. Then you might also need to find a `easy-install.pth` in a similar `site-packages` directory (most likely the same), and in this file delete the line mentioning `MyProject`.