Testing against local package before pushing update to PyPI
Let's say I have a package abc that I've published to PyPI.
I have other local projects that use abc. Of course, I'd like to be able to update abc locally and test against this version before pushing out to PyPI.
Here's one approach I'm using:

Make sure package is not in pip list output. I.e. uninstall if necessary.
Set PYTHONPATH to include the path to the local package

Then, if I want to test against the officially published abc package later, I can have another venv environment in which to install abc and test again there.
The benefit to the PYTHONPATH approach is that any change made to abc locally will immediately be available to any project importing it.
Question
Is this the recommended workflow? Is there another recommended way?

If I understand you correctly you can install the package in your other local project in editable mode, e.g. pip install -e <path to your abc package>. Then every change you do to abc package is reflected in your project immediately.

Docs: pip install -e … python setup.py develop.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576933/7976758 This how to uninstall editable (develop) install: python setup.py develop -u
