# "pip install --editable ./" vs "python setup.py develop"

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

Is there any significant difference between

```
pip install -e /path/to/mypackage
```

and the setuptools variant?

```
python /path/to/mypackage/setup.py develop
```

Comment: This appears to be an updated link describing development mode: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=development%20mode#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode

Comment: if you are interested in uninstall (packages in development/editable mode) try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e

Comment: I am afraid to ask it independently, but are these 2 ways the better ways to call an own-written module than "os.sys.append/insert" and PYTHONPATH change?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try to avoid calling `setup.py` directly, it will not properly tell pip that you've installed your package.

With `pip install -e`:

> For local projects, the “SomeProject.egg-info” directory is created
> relative to the project path. This is one advantage over just using
> `setup.py develop`, which creates the “egg-info” directly relative the
> current working directory.

More: [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#editable-installs)

Also read the setuptools' [docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=development%20mode#development-mode).

Comment: Does user have to run 'python setup.py sdist' again after making the file change for the change to take effect?

Comment: however if you need to debug (the setup.py file itself) with 'set_trace' then 'python setup.py develop' makes it possible

Comment: @sobolevn I am afraid to ask it independently, but are these 2 ways the better ways to call an own-written module than "os.sys.append/insert" and PYTHONPATH change?

Answer (score 88):

One more difference: `pip install -e` uses wheel while
`python setup.py develop`
doesn't use it.

With `install`, you could achieve the same behavior by using
`pip install -e /path/to/package --no-use-wheel`

More info on wheels : [python wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/)

Comment: Note that, according to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/, 
`--no-use-wheel` DEPRECATED in favour of `--no-binary :all:`

Comment: Can we do pip install -e for package produced using sdist?

Answer (score 47):

Another difference that may favor `pip install -e` is that if your project has dependencies in `install_requires` in `setup.py`, then `pip install -e .` installs dependencies with pip, while `python setup.py develop` can install with `easy_install`, and may cause problems re: 'egg-info' as mentioned above. When `install-requires` uses `dependency_links` with custom git URLs, with attached egg identifiers, this can be especially annoying.

Comment: this totally explains why my private package was failing to be installed. it's on my devpi server not pypi.  thanks.

Comment: When you say package becomes editable, Do you mean user will have to run 'python setup.py sdist' again after making change to package file? Or running above command is not required?

Comment: @variable when you install a local package with `pip install -e .`, it essentially makes a symlink in the relevant Python site-packages directory to point to your working copy. As code changes are made to that working copy, it is instantly reflected in the "installed" version, so you do not need to re-run installation commands as you go. This is primarily useful for developing in a repository that represents an installable package, but can also be handy for e.g. writing some collection of modules with only absolute imports, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another difference: when you run `python setup.py develop` for a version that is considered a pre-release (perhaps because you're running it from a git clone when not having checked out a release), then you will enable installation of **pre-releases of your dependencies**. On the other hand, with `pip install --editable` you would have to pass `--pre` explicitly if you want these pre-releases.

(See the [CI log with pre-releases accidentally used](https://travis-ci.com/github/Telecominfraproject/oopt-gnpy/jobs/353680894) and compare that to [a fixed build here](https://travis-ci.com/github/Telecominfraproject/oopt-gnpy/jobs/354005304).)