# sudo pip install -e

Tags: python, django, pip

I faced the line below when I installed **geonode** for development.

```
sudo pip install -e .
```

Here is the link: http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/install/custom_install.html

But I could not understand what **-e .** means. May be it referenced to my requirements.txt Can someone explain me, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pip install --editable ./" vs "python setup.py develop"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop)

Comment: No @matino, that was another question.

Answer (score 2):

Pip install Options:

```
-e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.  
-r, --requirement <file>    Install from the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.
```

In `sudo pip install -e .`
The `.` specifies the current directory path and the above pip command will try to search for setup.py file to install the project in develop mode.

Comment: Thanks, @Mani Kandan, got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `pip install --help` shows the following for `-e`:

```
-e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e.
                            setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
                            path or a VCS url.
```

Comment: I already have done this. But what is meant by the remaining **.** after -e?