# Trouble Using Command Prompt to Install Pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I need to process serial data using python for a project I am working on. However, the download of python 3 I have installed does not have the serial module already, so I have been working on trying to install the module.

To install the module, I downloaded PySerial 3.4, and tried to use the command prompt to install it. Specifically, I accessed the pyserial folder and found its address, directed the command prompt to that folder, and then prompted the system to install. What I typed into the command line looked as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\rinty\Desktop\pyserial-3.4

C:\Users\rinty\Desktop\pyserial-3.4>python setup.py install
```

However, when I do this nothing occurs. No download. When I instead type

```
C:\Users\rinty\Desktop\pyserial-3.4>setup.py install
```

The install will run, but presumably not through python. When I attempt to use the command

```
import serial
```

In the python IDE I still get a "No module named 'serial'" error in response.

Is there something I am missing? How do I get python to run the setup code for pyserial? Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE***

Instead of using the Windows command prompt, I tried using the Anaconda powershell. I then navigated to the pyserial folder and used the `pip` installation advice as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\rinty\Desktop\pyserial-3.4
pip install -e.
```

I got this response from the system:

```
Installing collected packages: pyserial
  Running setup.py develop for pyserial
Successfully installed pyserial
```

BUT, when I try to `import serial` in the Spyder IDE, it still tells me that no serial module can be found. Any advice?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pip install -e` ?

Comment: My command line in windows doesn't recognize ```pip``` as a command, so my guess would be no?

Comment: Did you check which venv using Spyder is using? Just a guess but maybe its not using the venv where pyserial was installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `--user` Tag**

Try using the `--user` (in the directory as follows) with the command as follows:

```
 python setup.py install --user
```

The `--user` option directs setup.py to install the package (for example, foo) in the user site-packages directory for the running Python

**Use `pip`**

I prefer to use pip in such cases (I use linux). Go to the respective folder and type the following:

```
sudo pip install -e
```

This command will search for the setup.py on its own. Refer to this answer for a better understanding of how this command works [sudo pip install -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596148/sudo-pip-install-e)

**Use *PyCharm* instead of *Spider***

Since I had been using Linux for so long, I was very inexperienced with windows python. `--user` worked for me in most cases. But, many such problems can be solved with **PyCharm**, especially those that arise due to different versions of python on the same machine. You can choose from the UI itself which python-interpreter you want to use and you can uninstall modules for that particular version. You can even create virtual environments.

Following are the steps:

1) Install PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

2) Go to File Menu. Click on settings

3) Chose the **Interpreter**

[image]

4) **Install module:**

[image]

Let me know if this doesn't work :)

Comment: It did wait a while to process when I used your ```--user``` method. However, python still says I don't have a serial module. I'm wondering if it has something to do with me using the Spyder IDE?

Comment: That could be a reason... Let me give you a shortcut - use PyCharm. I'll change my answer