# virtualenv use library from source

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is there a way to use a library that I built from source in virtualenv? All user documentation is about pip install normally. One option is to use --system-site-packages since library is built from source globally. But I don't want that.

Comment: can't you build the library again in the virtual environment?

Comment: You should look at `pip install --editable .`. It will install the current directory in the virtualenv (it should be activated so that `pip` is the virtualenv one). Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop)

Comment: @Bakuriu tnx solved my problem. If you answer it I accept pip install -e /path/to/package --no-binary :all:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by

```
 pip install -e /path/to/package --no-binary :all:
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop) helped