# Import a library which is in a sibling of the current folder

Tags: python, import, directory, python-import

With the folder structure

```
lib/
    abcd/
        __init.py__
        lib.py
app.py
```

the code

```
from lib.abcd import lib
```

works. But with this file structure:

```
bin/
    app.py
lib/
    abcd/
        __init.py__
        lib.py
```

the code

```
from ..lib.abcd import lib
```

gives an import error.

**How to do the `import` properly when the library is in a sibling of the current folder?** (or subfolder of a sibling folder)

I know that there might some hack that involves adding `lib/` to the PATH, but is there an elegant Pythonic solution?

If not, is there a real internal reason to prevent users to do this simple import in a simple way?

Comment: Normally you just cannot. As your top level directory is `bin`. To achieve it, you need to add parent directory into `sys.path`. And then import it as `from lib.abcd import lib`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Sraw. Isn't there an easier solution?

Comment: Surely there is... Moving that `lib` to `bin`. I understand your project strucutre. If you want to insist on it, I recommend you to add a bash script for launching purpose. In that script you can use `PYTHONPATH=your_parent_directory python app.py` to launch your app.

Comment: Just to clarify, based on the code and these comments: Is there no parent folder here? Is this the _complete_ folder structure your project?

Comment: IMHO you are doing it wrong. You should distinguish between the layout of the source code and the layout of an installed software. When you install the software the `lib` will be installed in the site-packages of the python interpreter and you are done, you can put  `app.py` in a standard `bin` directory and it will always work independently of where it is. During development you simply flag the root directory as sources root and you are done, or you use a virtualenv where you do a [`pip install -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop)

Comment: @Bakuriu Sometimes yes, but sometimes you have a big project `project123/` and you have code in multiple subfolders of `project123/`. You don't necessarily want the libs to be elsewhere. There should be a way to do the import, in a simple way, like in nearly *all other languages* à la `#include "../x.h"`.

Comment: @Basj There is no need for such a thing. In python the main concept is the package. Everything inside the package can import anything else using relative imports. If you want to access to something outside that you access it via a plain `import` and it's whoever runs the code that should define the environment correctly. If you want to always use relative imports the solution is simple: just put everything into a big main package. I don't really see any value in this and Python is simply not designed for that. If you buy a bike then decide to remove the saddle and sit on it it's your choice.

Answer (score 2):

## Methods to do this

---

**Method #1: Using the sys module:**  You can easily accomplish what you are trying to do using the `sys` module. To import the `lib` package, you can use one of the two codes listed below:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('<PATH_TO_LIB_FOLDER>')

from lib.abcd import lib
```

or

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<PATH_TO_LIB_FOLDER>')
```

---

**Method #2: Using the os module:** Another method is to use the `os` module. Here is an example code that imports the `lib` module using the `os` module by invoking the `os.path.join` method:

```py
import os

path = os.path.join("<PATH>/lib/abcd", "lib")
from lib.abcd import lib
```

---

**Method #3: Add the module to your PYTHONPATH:** This is not the best method in most cases, but if you don't want to keep using the `sys` or `os` module to import `lib`, this is ideal. All you have to do is type this in your bash terminal:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=<PATH_TO_LIB> python lib.py
```

Then in your python shell you can import it like this:

```py
from lib.abcd import lib
```

---

**Method #4: Combine the sys and os module (recommended):** This is the most efficient method and will save you a lot of time. This code combines the `os` and `sys` module like this:

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'lib')))
```

Then you can import your module with ease like this:

```py
from lib.abcd import lib
```

---

#### How all the codes work:

All the codes above are very simple. All the examples except for *"Method #3"*, add your module to the `PYTHONPATH` temporarily. *"Method #3"* on the other hand, adds the module to your `PYTHONPATH` permanently.

Comment: What new information did you add? These are both path manipulation, which I already mentioned, and is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Method #2 does not add anything to your `PYTHONPATH`. All that does is create the string `path` which is, e.g. on *nix, `"<PATH>/lib/abcd/lib"`. And for method #3, you probably shouldn't overwrite `PYTHONPATH` but rather prepend to it.

Comment: Method 2 is completely unrelated to the question (at least the *os* part).

Comment: @CristiFati -- Method 2 is just a way to make it work

Comment: Maybe, but `os.path.join` is completely useless there, therefore *os* and then the method itself..

Comment: These all add to the path at runtime, and your answer #3 assumes a bash environment configured in a very specific way which isn't part of the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

## Surface level look

Normally, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and `sys.path` which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

The reason you don't see this problem for importing installed modules is because they are installed in a location that is already on your path, or the location is added to the path by the installing utility (`pip` for example).

You can add to the Python path at runtime:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '../lib')

    import file
```

You can also use `sys.path.append('../lib')`, but then it will be searched for last in your path and may be overridden by previous path entries.

I have read through the [import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) extensively, and as far as I can tell, the answer to your question is no, there is no way to do this in a purely "Pythonic" way.

## More in depth look:

Looking deeper into the [import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) explains this:

> The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope. The search operation of the import statement is defined as a call to the **__import__()** function, with the appropriate arguments. The return value of **__import__()** is used to perform the name binding operation of the import statement.

Looking more closely at [__import__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__):

> ### __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0)
>
> **Note**: This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming, unlike [importlib.import_module()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).
>
> This function is invoked by the import statement. It can be replaced (by importing the builtins module and assigning to builtins.__import__) in order to change semantics of the import statement, but doing so is strongly discouraged as it is usually simpler to use import hooks (see PEP 302) to attain the same goals and does not cause issues with code which assumes the default import implementation is in use. Direct use of __import__() is also discouraged in favor of [importlib.import_module()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).
>
> level specifies whether to use absolute or relative imports. 0 (the default) means only perform absolute imports. Positive values for level indicate the number of parent directories to search relative to the directory of the module calling __import__() (see PEP 328 for the details).

This makes me think that you can specify a `level` in some way that may make the import automatically look on the parent path. I'm guessing that when `import` is called from your `app.py` that is not in it's own directory, `level` is set to `0` and it searches the same level and deeper.

When you call `import` in `app.py` from a subfolder, `level` is still set to `0` and thus can't find the other directories above it. I am investigating a "Pythonic" way of setting this level to `1` when running your script which would appear to fix this problem.