# Python3 - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python

I have 2 folders:

```
my_python
     code.py

MyCode
     TestEntry.py
```

When I run the following commands:

```
cd /data/my_python
python3 code.py
```

The above works.

However, if I in my home folder and then run this:

```
python3 /data/my_python/code.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/my_python/code.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TestEntry import TestEntry
ImportError: No module named 'TestEntry'
```

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../MyCode'))
from TestEntry import TestEntry
TestEntry().start(507,"My Param1","/param2",'.xyz',509)
```

Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Why did you expect that this module exists?

Comment: If I go to the folder - using `cd /data/my_python`, and run - `python3 code.py`, it does work. Just not from a different folder.

Comment: If you run the script from a different location, the path you add to `sys.path` will no longer be correct. You would have to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but how to do it?

Comment: By writing the correct path instead of the wrong path? It seems it would have to be `data/MyCode`, not `../MyCode`.

Comment: Could you please give the file structure?

Comment: I have 2 folders - my_python where my main python is and MyCode where the library to be imported is.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a relative path to `sys` with your line `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../MyCode'))`. Instead, you need to import relative to that file you are calling. Try this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
from TestEntry import TestEntry
TestEntry().start(507, "My Param1", "/param2", '.xyz', 509)
```

Comment: But I need to go to another folder to get TestEntry which is /data/MyCode

Comment: Yeah, doing `os.path.dirname` twice goes back 2 folders. If that doesn't work, try with only one. The key here is the `__file__` that you pass into it. It's the path to the file that runs this code. From there, you need to see how many levels you need to go back so python can find your module.

Comment: Do I need to add 2 lines: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) and sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../MyCode'))

Comment: No, just the first one `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` or `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score 0):

That happens because, as @mkrieger1 mentioned, your `sys.path` gets messed up. I have a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622024/import-a-library-which-is-in-a-sibling-of-the-current-folder) which explains how to set it. By `sys.path` getting messed up, I mean that python will look in the dir that you are running from, not the dir that the script you are running is in. Here is the recommended method:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'MyCode')))
... (your code)
```

or

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', 'MyCode')))
... (your code)
```

This way python will look in the dir of the file you are running as well.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Should I add both the lines -- sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) and sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../MyCode'))

Comment: @dang -- Maybe. If you gave a better file structure explanation, we could be of better help.

Comment: I have added folder explanation in the question.

Comment: For some reason, both didn't work, giving the same error

Comment: I am in my home folder - `cd ~` and ran `python3 /data/my_python/code.py`