# should I always use one of pip install editable or setup.py develop in my project?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When exactly should I use either `pip install -e` or `python setup.py develop` in my project? is it always necessary to do one of them? can't I just work with the scripts themselves as they are?

related to
["pip install --editable ./" vs "python setup.py develop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop)

Comment: What exactly do you want to know beyond what is explained in the other question?

Comment: The purpose of the `develop` command (and it also addresses `pip`) is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install

Comment: It is not in general necessary to use it. If you can work with your code without using it then it is not necessary for you.

Comment: @ihadanny mkrieger1 already answered: use it when you need it, there is no obligation. Now, more of an opinion than an answer, from my point of view: you should always use the `src` project directory layout (one discussion on this [here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/)), and then it will become obvious that you need the _develop_ or _editable_ mode when working on your project.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use them only when you need to import something from a sibling folder or any other import problems.

[Take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)